# Is there any way to rearrange select result columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, pivot

I want to return one student in one row here is my select :

```
select Name from student
```

Result:

```
 Name
 Emre
```

My second select is my teachers but I still want to bring one row:

```
select Name from teacher
```

Result:

```
Name
 John 
 Adam
```

And I want this output

```
 Name   1.Teacher   2.Teacher
 Emre   John        Adam
```

Is it possible to do that in one row ?

Comment: How do you know that `Emre` has those teachers?  Can you post your table definitions?

Comment: What connects the teacher and students?

Comment: This is usually referred to as pivoting, but if there are an unknown number of result *columns*, I'd usually recommend doing it in a reporting tool or in some other language rather than SQL. There are some ugly ways to achieve dynamic pivots but I'm not a fan. Of course, I'm assuming a dynamic result. If it's not dynamic, how do you determine that John goes in the 1 column and Adam goes in the 2 column?

Comment: There is no connection because i cannot make joining think about this tables totally different from each other

Comment: @Emre Then how do you know what student has which teachers?  Or is it just random?  You have to have some table that associates the teach to each student.

Comment: Yes it's possible. Should we close your question since we've answered?

Comment: student is static but teachers is dinamic you are right. My target is bringing one row. Teachers have order I can build strings for column names dinamically but i dont know how can i make two column next each other and add them to other select result

Comment: SELECT 'Emre' AS Name, 'John' AS "1.Teacher", 'Adam' AS "2.Teacher"

Comment: bluefeet there is no connection between them and i dont want to know which student associates the teacher. i just want to know one student and rest of them is teacher

Comment: Teachers is not static

Comment: @Emre What if you have 50 students and 500 teachers, you are going to repeat the teachers for each student? That makes no sense.

Comment: ok i solved it with improving dnoeth's answer. I can select teacher and after can create some strings dinamically then i guess i can use exec select statement and there is one row :) thank you so much all.

Comment: there is no 50 student just "1" and it possible 500 teacher but in my Scenario there is max 5 teacher.

Comment: @Emre the query that you are using isn't actually querying your database, you are just using hard-coded string values.

Comment: There's probably a better approach for what you REALLY want than using a database for it.

Comment: Yes maybe for example this student just recorded database and you do not want to record more information about him and if you want to give him 5 teacher name from english teacher table to inform in paper this will be useful for you

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately you didn't provide any details on how the `student` is associated with each `teacher` so I am assuming that you have a table that joins the two similar to the following:

```
CREATE TABLE student_teacher
    ([student_id] int, [teacher_id] int)
;
```

If you have this type of join table, then you can use the PIVOT function to get the result.  If you have a limited number of teachers for each student, then you can hard-code your query using `row_number()` to assign a sequenced value for each teach per student:

```
select student_name, teacher1, teacher2
from
(
  select s.name student_name,
    t.name teacher_name,
    'teacher'
      + cast(row_number() over(partition by s.id
                                order by t.id) as varchar(10)) seq
  from student s
  inner join student_teacher st
    on s.id = st.student_id
  inner join teacher t
    on st.teacher_id = t.id
) d
pivot
(
  max(teacher_name)
  for seq in (teacher1, teacher2)
) piv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5aaaa/2).  But if you have an unknown amount of teachers, then you will look at using dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ', ' + QUOTENAME('teacher'
                                                       +cast(row_number() over(partition by student_id
                                                                              order by teacher_id) as varchar(10))) 
                    from student_teacher
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT student_name,' + @cols + ' 
            from 
            (
              select s.name student_name,
                t.name teacher_name,
                ''teacher''
                  + cast(row_number() over(partition by s.id
                                            order by t.id) as varchar(10)) seq
              from student s
              inner join student_teacher st
                on s.id = st.student_id
              inner join teacher t
                on st.teacher_id = t.id
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(teacher_name)
                for seq in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute sp_executesql @query;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5aaaa/3)